# Table View Cell class's view showing nil

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, delegates, tableview

This is the code that I have for Table View's cell class  [RegisterCell class (Table view cell)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lqsa.png) and this is the code in my controller [part 1 (view did load, view did appear functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s2mh.png), [cellForRowAt function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wySsA.png) and [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRI8j.png).
My goal is to make the horizontalview in registerCell's class change the background color every-time the corresponding textfield is clicked (or typed in). Whats the issue for this error? Any help is highly appreciated.
This is what I mean by corresponding texfield and view [the controller generates 6 of those](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2OiP.png)

Code shown below for registerCell class

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class RegisterCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate{
    
    @IBOutlet weak var userInfoLbl: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var userInfoTxtField: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var horizontalView: UIView!
   
    
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField){
       horizontalView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 175.0/210.0, blue: 212.0/188.0, alpha: 1)
         }
}
```

Code shown below for RegisterViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    editButtonColorAndShapes()
    configure()
    self.tableView.separatorColor = .clear;
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
   


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    configure()
    self.tableView.register(RegisterCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "registerCell")
    editButtonColorAndShapes()
   //r
}

 @objc func textFieldDidChange(textfield: UITextField) {
      

        switch textfield.tag {
        case 0:
           firstname  = textfield.text!

        case 1:
            lastname = textfield.text!

        case 2:
           pnumber = textfield.text!

        case 3:
            email  = textfield.text!

        case 4:
            passwrd   = textfield.text!
            textfield.isSecureTextEntry = true

        case 5:
            zipCode = textfield.text!
        default:
            break
        }
        
    registerModell = RegisterModel(fname: firstname, lname: lastname, fhone: pnumber, mail: email, pass: passwrd, zip: zipCode)
    }

extension RegisterViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return titles.count
    }
    

    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "registerCell",
                                                for: indexPath) as! RegisterCell
    
       
       
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.userInfoLbl?.text = titles[indexPath.row]
        cell.userInfoLbl?.textColor = UIColor(named: "aquamarine")
        cell.horizontalView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 175.0/210.0, blue: 212.0/188.0, alpha: 0.25)
        cell.userInfoLbl?.addCharacterSpacing(kernValue: 4.57)
 cell.userInfoTxtField.delegate = delegatez
        cell.userInfoTxtField.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.userInfoTxtField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
        cell.configure()
        
        
        
        return cell
   
       
    }
```

Comment: Please edit this post and add code using the “{}” button. Code as an image is disliked.

Comment: Totally stupid question, but I can't see whether you hooked up the @IBOutlet horizontalView to the view in the register cell.

Comment: @MacUserT I did :( i checked all the connections

Comment: One thing I'd like to confirm with you before trying to fix this for you inside of a test project. Did you hook up the outlets in code connected as the files owner or the `UITableViewCell` (It needs to be the `UITableViewCell`)

Comment: @Demented07 you mean if I connected  these outlets
    IBOutlet weak var userInfoLbl: UILabel!
    
    IBOutlet weak var userInfoTxtField: UITextField!
    
    IBOutlet weak var horizontalView: UIView!   
to registerCell?

Comment: I'll copy your code into a test project and see if I can work out where the error is coming from.

Comment: @Demented07 thanks so much. I didnt copy all of the code, only the parts that are relevant. Let me know if you need anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My only guess to why your `horizontalView` had an error is due to the `IBOutlets` not being connected properly somehow (maybe delete the outlet and then replace it again) However, I have gotten the `horizontalView` to change its own background colour when the user taps inside of the `textField` to begin typing/editing.

The reason for why even without the error you were getting, the horizontal view was not changing color was due to the fact that you had not set the `Delegate` of the text field to its cell class.

> NOTE: The delegate listens out for and handles events such as touching and typing therefore it is required for your desired outcome.

This is how I did it:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! RegisterCell
    cell.userInfoTxtField.delegate = cell
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much!! It worked :) can you please explain? Im new to iOS. This is what I had. Why did this not work?
let delegatez = RegisterCell()
 cell.userInfoTxtField.delegate = delegatez 
What was wrong with this code?

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `RegisterCell` it has no reference to the `UITableViewCell` who's background color you want to change (in other words your creating a new cell and then setting the text view's `delegate` to that cell but that cell is not the one which is going to be displayed within the table view). Anything which I have mentioned which you do not understand please just ask and I will try to explain it the best I can.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you place `textField` in a contentView of `RegisterCell`, you could refer to a cell as a superview of a superview for the textField. After that you could change background color for `horizontalView`:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if let cell = textField.superview?.superview as? RegisterCell {
        cell.horizontalView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 175.0/210.0, blue: 212.0/188.0, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```